# Atualizar atributo da tabela, via Form <?php $PHP_SELF ?>

Tags: php, formulário

Tentei fazer um código aqui, mas não deu muito certo... sabem me informar onde está o erro?

```
<?
     if(isset($_POST['reseta_wl'])) {
        $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = '';

        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

        if(! $conn ) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $id = $_SESSION['s_usuario'];

        $sql = "UPDATE game ". "SET credito = 30 ". 
           "WHERE id = $id" ;
        mysql_select_db('gbwc');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "Updated data successfully\n";

        mysql_close($conn);
     } else {
        ?>
          <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
           <input type="button" name="reseta_wl" value="Resetar">
          </form>
        <?
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: Que erro aparece?

Comment: O erro já começa quando leio `mysql` no código. E não ta dando `echo` no `PHP_SELF`.

Comment: Não está dando erro algum... Na verdade não está ocorrendo nenhuma ação quando clico no botão!

Comment: @EduardoHenrique, tenho no gitHub uma classe PDO. Fique a vontade para usar. https://github.com/LucaoA/connectionPDO/blob/master/Connection.php

Comment: Só pra constar, se é pra mandar pra mesma página, basta omitir o action. MAS, não acho ruim você especificar o endereço, pois apesar de não ser uma coisa muito comum de acontecer, explicitar o URL, evita "clickjacking" caso alguém chame seu form num `iframe`. Como disse o @MagicHat, para acessar o PHP_SELF se usa `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`

Answer (score 1):

Como dito pelos colégas no comentário, funções mysql devem ser substituídas por funções mysqli.

Em relação ao erro do seu código o por si só não é uma função de saída.

Altere para action="`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`"

para maiorea detalhes acesse:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php

e http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

Vē se ajuda e posta um retorno.

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei até este resultado...

```
<?
 if(isset($_POST['reseta_wl'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['s_usuario'];
    $result = mysql_query("select * from game where id = '$id'");
    $usr = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $coin = $usr['credito'];
    $sql = "UPDATE game SET credito = $coin-20 WHERE id = '$id'";
    if(mysql_query($sql, $link)){
       echo "Atualizado com sucesso.";
    } else{
       echo "Not able to execute $sql.";
    }


    mysql_close($link);
 } else {
    ?>
      <form method="post" action="">
       <input type="submit" name="reseta_wl" value="Resetar">
      </form>
    <?
 }?>
```

Mas o select q estou tentando dar na tabela não está funcionando, visto que a operação matemática não está sendo efetuada.
Alguém sabe onde estou errando?

Comment: Aconselho vc abrir uma nova pergunta com seu código, questionando sobre operações aritméticas em consulta sql...

Comment: Recomendo adicionar uma linha , pra debug, logo apos a primeira query: echo mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: Desta forma pode confirmar se ela está retornando valores.